# inline-block not working together with overflow-wrap for divs

Tags: html, css, overflow, inline, word-wrap

I have two `divs` that fit nicely on one line when using `display: inline-block`, but if one container now contains some very long word that I try to wrap with `overflow-wrap` and `word-break`, this container will move to the next line, what I want to avoid.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.bar {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
<div class="bar">
  barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbphzxwe/6/)

What I would want is this

```
foobarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar...
...barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want to have both the divs in the same line, consider wrapping them in a parent div with `display:flex`

Learn about [flexbox model here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Check here:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.bar {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}

div.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div>foo</div>
  <div class="bar">
    barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w82edmfh/)

Comment: @DonFuchs feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the divs a width. inline-block will take up as much space as it needs, so if its contents takes up the whole width of the viewport it acts like display:block.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kh8brp62/
Flexbox is a great solution to your problem, but you should also understand how inline-block works